# IIS 7.5 install error 80040154

Tags: iis-7.5

This is my error

I'm running Delphi 7 and was not able to start a Http web demo
I tried to install phalanger to see if that worked, only to get error 80040154
has any one seen this error before.
I believe I have run aspnet_regiis.exe -ir to install .net 4
phalanger says iis 7.5 is installed
I found it hard to produce a new site in ISS so I carefully modified the example to my needs. 
I'm questioning if I have done something wrong some were

Comment: Well, what careful modifications did you make?

Comment: I found out I needed windows 7 service pack 1 and its going a lot better.      I have learn how to get fast cgi going and think I will get thier documentation is not clear with my version of IIS 7.5 as changes have been made.